# Image Won't Spin When Hover

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm just doing a simple CSS/HTML spin animation for an image and when I hover on the image, it won't spin. I put the pseudo-class element in CSS already.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This is the CSS

```css
    .spin-image {
      display: flex;
      margin: auto;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      padding-left: 200px;
      transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .spin-image:hover {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
```

```html
    <div class ="different__box">
      <div class ="different__border"></div>
        <div class ="different__right-background">
          <div class ="spin-image">
            <img class="different__image-right" src ="./coffee-shop-assets/tiltedcan.png"/>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename `<div class ="spin-image">` to `<div class ="spin-animation">`

The class of the CSS style must match the class of the HTML element.

Comment: It seems the base code has been edited. This is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for other affecting factors. Your code is working just fine:

```css
.spin-image {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 200px;
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
}

.spin-image:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class ="different__box">
  <div class ="different__border"></div>
    <div class ="different__right-background">
      <div class ="spin-image">
        <img class="different__image-right" src ="https://picsum.photos/200/200"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```